# Why does a blackbody object emit light if it only absorbs light?

Tags: thermodynamics, statistical-mechanics, electromagnetic-radiation, visible-light, thermal-radiation

I have learned that a [blackbody](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Black_body) object only absorbs light and thus does not reflect any light. The blackbody object will, however, emit light, and none of this light is due to reflection. Where does this light/energy come from? I assume, given an atom, that the light emitted is due to excitation and decay of electron states. Is this correctly understood, and can there be other methods of emission?

Comment: please read this  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html

Answer (score 3, accepted):

The energy comes from whatever is keeping the blackbody in thermal equilibrium at its characteristic temperature even as it radiates energy away.

That can be the energy absorbed from its surroundings, or it can be some internal energy source.

Taking the Sun as an example - a cube of material inside the Sun (but not near the centre) emits an almost perfect blackbdy spectrum at a temperature characteristic of its position within the Sun (cooler as it gets closer to the surface). The energy comes from the radiation that the same cube of material absorbs from its immediate surroundings.

But we could consider a bigger picture and look at the Sun as a whole. It also emits a spectrum that *approximates* reasonably well to a blackbody. The energy for that radiation does not comes from radiation absorbed by the Sun as a whole, but is supplied by nuclear fusion reactions in its core.

If you are asking what microscopic processes give rise to the blackbody radiation, then there are many examples/duplicates of that question on Physics SE. The most general answer that can be given is that they are the microscopic inverse processes of whatever causes the blackbody to absorb all radiation incident upon it. Thus, as an example, the photosphere of the Sun is opaque across all visible wavelengths because visible photons can photodissociate electrons from H$^{-}$ ions that are present. The inverse process - photons emitted when electrons combine with hydrogen atoms - provides the blackbody continuum radiation.

Answer (score 1):

your assertion that a blackbody only emits and does not absorb is false. It absorbs and emits with equal ease, which characteristic allows it to come into *thermal *equilibrium* with its surroundings by exchanging energy back and forth until the temperature difference between them is zero. So, the energy of emission was picked up by absorption an instant prior.

Comment: But that isn't asserted in the question?

Answer (score 0):

The concept of a blackbody is a macroscopic one, it does not specify what it is made of or the microscopic mechanism in order to emit or absorb light. A blackbody just happens to emit thermal light with perfect emissitivity (and absorb with perfect absorptivity). Notice that you could ask the same question about any opaque material, why coal can emit thermal radiation?

Thermal radiation originates from charges, electric currents and dipoles that can appear momentaneously due to thermal fluctuations. The blackbody just happens to be able to so, emitting at every frequency according to Planck's law. Real objects are not perfect blackbodies because they allow or restrict certain energy transitions.

Comment: Okay, so the emitted energy originates from charges, electric currents and dipoles due to thermal fluctuations characteristic for the given system.

Comment: @RasmusAndersen yes, for the thermally emitted radiation, it is related to the response (the electric susceptibility) of the material.  It might be worth it to take a look at the [fluctuation–dissipation theorem](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Fluctuation-dissipation_theorem)

Answer (score 0):

The black body radiation stems from the heat or temperature of the black body and has nothing to do with absorption.At room temperature it does not emit light in the frequency range of your  seeing, so it adsorbs visible light .

Comment: please read this  http://hyperphysics.phy-astr.gsu.edu/hbase/mod6.html